# 4 different letters and 4 addressed envelopes.

Tags: combinatorics

Question is : In how many ways can the letters be put into the envelopes, so that at least one letter goes to the correct address ?

Answer is 15. 
All i could think of is : 4 envelop choices for each letter, so 4*4 = 16.

A little fertilizer for my withered grey-matter ?

Comment: Use the inclusion-exclusion formula.

Comment: You have to subtract the number of derangements of four objects from the $4!$ ways of placing one letter in each envelope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4!-!4=24-9=15$$

${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What is !4? I have not seen this sign before.